# Using web.config for redirections

Tags: asp.net, web-config, redirect, http-redirect

I'm not very clear on how to use redirections in web.config.

Basically, I have a situation where an external source is providing my website with some HTML including relative links which in my case are not correct.

The link provided:
   /FinanceApply/

Should point to:
    www.MYURL.co.uk/PaymentTemplates/V12Checkout.aspx

So I added

```
  <location path="/FinanceApply/">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://www.MYURL.co.uk/PaymentTemplates/V12Checkout.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Permanent"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
```

But for some reason this completely breaks the site. I have other similar redirect statements in web.config which work fine though.

So how:

- Do I add this redirect?
- Do I ensure that any form posts to the `/FinanceApply/` path are passed to the redirected page?

Comment: What do you mean "completely breaks the site"? You need to clearly describe the issue.

Comment: Server Error

500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: ^ That is what I mean

Comment: No error detail. If there was I'd have a go at figuring it out myself!

Comment: Look at the event logs on the server, there should be information there about the error.

Comment: It's shared hosting, I don't have access to the server logs. I'll ask my hosts.

Comment: Does the site work locally?

Comment: Sorry, I've only just had chance to try. No, it doesn't, the error is clearer, but still offers no real explanation:
HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.
Config Source:
    2: <configuration>
    3:   <location path="/FinanceApply/">
    4:     <system.webServer>

Comment: Obviously it is a problem with the web.config file, but I don't know why as the other redirects I have in there work.

Comment: Right -  I have it working now, the `/` characters in the `path` parameter are not allowed.
So, part 2 of my question was "How do I preserve the POST data in a redirect?"

Comment: Ah - the answer is a 307 redirect.
  <location path="FinanceApply">
    <system.webServer>
      <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://mydomain.co.uk/PaymentTemplates/V12Checkout.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Temporary"/>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, anyone who stumbles across a similar issue, the answer to my problems were twofold:

Firstly, the `/` character in the `path` parameter of my redirect rule in web.config was invalid.

Secondly, the answer to preserving the POST data is a 307 redirect instead of a 301.

To achieve this, the correct web.config entry is:

```
<location path="FinanceApply">
   <system.webServer>
     <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="https://mydomain.co.uk/PaymentTemplates/V12Checkout.aspx" httpResponseStatus="Temporary"/>
   </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Note `httpResponseStatus="Temporary"`, this gives the 307.